# UITableViewScrollPositionTop on the last UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview

I am having a hard time trying to make the very last `UITableViewCell` from my table to get to the `UITableViewScrollPositionTop`.

The behavior I would expect is:

On `didSelectTableAtindexPath:lastindex`, the table would bring the last cell all the way up to the top position... I would do whatever is needed, then, I could resume the positioning (pretty much like what happens when we use a textField inside the cell and the keyboard fires up)

Does anyone know how can we get that kind of behavior?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got it by myself actually...
If anyone is having the same issue, here is what you should do:
right before using the `scrollToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated:`
use:

```
aTableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(aTableView.contentInset.top, 
                                           aTableView.contentInset.left, 
                                           aTableView.contentInset.bottom+300, 
                                           aTableView.contentInset.right);
```

do what you have to do and then:

```
aTableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(aTableView.contentInset.top, 
                                           aTableView.contentInset.left, 
                                           aTableView.contentInset.bottom-300, 
                                           aTableView.contentInset.right);
```

the only problem is that the comming back from the inset is not animated, but I guess you can set an animation to smooth the transition...

Answer (score 0):

Use this delegate methods to scroll top or bottom

```
scrollToNearestSelectedRowAtScrollPosition:animated:
scrollToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated:
selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition:
```

Comment: Yes, I am already using them, the thing is, when I for instance select the last cell and set it to go to the first position, it won't get there, as the content is out of bounds. The issue here is dynamically configure the Bounds/Insets/ScrollViewFrame, so that it will get there. The problem is that setting those values dynamically, the table view loses the reference to the relative position of the cells. I wonder if anyone got a solution for the same problem... :P but thanks for the answer!